# How to port my Windows app to a Mac if I don't have a Mac

Tags: windows, porting

I have a Windows app (C++ using Visual Studio) and I want to port it to a Mac. Must I get a Mac to do this? It'd be nice to port it without having to spend too much money, even better for free. 
Thanks everybody.

Comment: App sounds C-like. But to be sure, specifying the programming language would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to hack a VmWare image together - I had it done sometime back. It takes quite an effort because it's not officially supported but it can be done. On my image the mouse didn't work so I had to use the arrow keys on the keyboard to move the pointer but most people had no such issues. Drivers were the biggest problem. After OS X was installed, all applications (the ones that I tried) worked fine but they were somewhat slow and the mouse issue made things somewhat painful (but bearable).